# Extract particular data from Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, twitter

I'm doing real time streaming on Twitter and wonder is there a way to extract only messages and certain values from Kafka topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ksqlDB to do this. For example:

```sql
ksql> CREATE STREAM TWEETS WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='twitter_01', VALUE_FORMAT='Avro');

ksql> SELECT USER->SCREENNAME, TEXT FROM TWEETS WHERE TEXT LIKE '%cool%' EMIT CHANGES;

+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|USER__SCREENNAME   |TEXT                                                                                      |
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|MobileGist         |This is super cool!! Great work @houchens_kim!                                            |
```

You can also build a new topic with the results of this if you want

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM COOL_TWEETS AS SELECT USER->SCREENNAME, TEXT FROM TWEETS WHERE TEXT LIKE '%cool%' EMIT CHANGES;
```

Since you tagged Python it's worth pointing out that you can call ksqlDB using its REST API from Python. [Here's an example](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/wifi-fun/telegram_ksqldb_bots/push_bot.py#L25-L78).

Ref: [Exploring ksqlDB with Twitter Data](https://www.confluent.io/blog/stream-processing-twitter-data-with-ksqldb/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-04&utm_term=rmoff-devx)